# Adding scroll loop to masonry gallery in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gallery

I'm trying to modify the [WP-Canvas Gallery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-gallery/) plugin to endlessly repeat the images in the gallery it is showing when the user scrolls down to the end of the page. The gallery is located at http://www.armijostudio.com.

I have VERY limited knowledge of JavaScript, but here's what I've tried:

In the code, I've found the place where the gallery is created:

```
var initGallery = function() {
    $('.gallery-masonry').each( function() {
        var $container = $(this);
        var $posts = $container.children('.gallery-item');

        $posts.hide();

        // keeps the media elements from calculating for the full width of the post
        runMasonry(0, $container, $posts);

        // we are going to append masonry items as the images load
        $container.wcGalleryMasonryImagesReveal( $posts );

        $(window).resize(function() {
            runMasonry(0, $container, $posts);
        }); 
});
```

Before the closing bracket, I've tried re-running initGallery when the page is scrolled to the bottom and the following:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
            if (document.documentElement.clientHeight + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height()) {
                var $container = $(this);
                var $posts = $container.children('.gallery-item');

                $posts.hide();

                // keeps the media elements from calculating for the full width of the post
                runMasonry(0, $container, $posts);

                // we are going to append masonry items as the images load
                $container.wcGalleryMasonryImagesReveal( $posts );

                $(window).resize(function() {
                    runMasonry(0, $container, $posts);
                }); 
            }
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thank you all in advance!